# PHP Login without redirect.

Tags: php, html

Please assist. I have a login page that I want to basically do the following:

1.) Login Form (Username and Password)
2.) Use cookies, so if the user comes back they do not have to login
3.) When the user logs in, rather that redirect to another page, just refresh the current page, replacing the login form with a "Welcome "Username"" display.

I am very close, but I am getting an error at lines 83 and 84. It does show logged in successfully. (       $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM phpfb_users WHERE user='".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
        $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);)

Any ideas what I am missing. Also, this login script is being used within Joomla. I am not using Joomla Authentication, as the program I am running has its own login process.

```html
<?
  session_start();

$subtitle="Login";
ob_start();
require("header2.php");
//Get any form data.
$football->WhoOnlineDelete;

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if ($_POST)
{

    if ($username=="")
    {
                $football->ErrorMessage("Please enter a username.");
    }
        elseif ($password=="")
    {
                $football->ErrorMessage("Please enter your password.");
    }
      else
    {
//Verify the password and redirect to default page if correct.
     $sql="select * from ".$football->prefix."users where user = '".$username."'";
         $rs = $football->dbQuery($sql,$football->database);
         $row = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
         $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
      if($rows == 0)
      {
                $football->ErrorMessage("User '".$username."' not found.");
      }
      elseif (md5($password) != $row->password)
      {
                $football->ErrorMessage("Incorrect password, please reenter.");
      }
       else
      {

        $user=$row->user;
        if ($row->name =="") {
        $uname=$row->user;
        } else {
        $uname=$row->name;
        }
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

      }

    }


  }


//}
  else
{
//Set test cookie.
  setcookie("football","peanutbutter",0,"/",$football->domain,0);
}
?>
<div>
<div style="display:block;margin:0px auto;">
<?php if(empty($_SESSION["user"])) { ?>
<form name="loginform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">

 <div class="error-message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div> 
 <div class="field-group">
  <div><label for="login">Username: </label>
  <input name="username" type="text" class="input-field">
 
<label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" class="input-field"> 
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-submit-button"></span></div>
 </div>       
</form>
<?php 
} else { 
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM phpfb_users WHERE user='".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
 $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<form action="" method="post" id="frmLogout">
<div class="member-dashboard">Welcome <?php echo $user; ?>, You have successfully logged in!<br>
Click to <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" class="logout-button">.</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      document.loginform.username.focus();
      document.loginform.username.select();
</script>
```

Comment: `mysql_` and `mysqli_` dont work together. Use `mysqli_`. You are open to SQL injections, use parameterized queries. You should not be using md5 for password hashing anymore. Use the PHP functions `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: What is the error you currently get? Those are just issues I noticed.

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You can use `header('Location:login.php')` to redirect to the login page, then check if a user is already logged in. Then display different `html` tags whether a user is logged in or not

Comment: `md5()`is obsolete for hashing passwords and should *not be used*. PHP provides [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).